# How to test the UAE number in Arabic using RegEx?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, arabic, arabic-support

```
func isValidUAENumber() -> Bool {
    let phoneRegExAr = "^(?:\\+٩٧١|٠(٠٩٧١)?)(?:[٢٣٤٦٧٩]|٥[٠١٢٥٦])[٠-٩]{٧}$"
    let phoneRegEx = "^(?:\\+971|0(0971)?)(?:[234679]|5[01256])[0-9]{7}$"
    let isArabic = true //(or false based on some condition)
    let useRegEx = isArabic ? phoneRegExAr : phoneRegEx
    let phonePredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", useRegEx)
    return phonePredicate.evaluate(with: self)
}
```

So this code is working fine with the UAE numbers in English and now I am trying to check the same with UAE numbers in Arabic. My mind suggested me to convert the english numbers RegEx to Arabic numbers RegEx so I used online translation tool to convert english to Arabic numbers and here I have the Arabic numbers RegEx but app will get crash as I have used the Arabic regex to check for a valid UAE number in Arabic:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching,
>   reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL (string +٩٧١٥٢٥٣٩٥٧٥٧,
>   pattern ^(?:+٩٧١|٠(٠٩٧١)?)(?:[٢٣٤٦٧٩]|٥[٠١٢٥٦])[٠-٩]{٧}$, case 0,
>   canon 0)'

Any one came across this situation before? Please help.

**Update 1**:

This is how Arabic RegEx looks in Xcode?
[image]

Sample numbers:

1. 072466666 (٠٧٢٤٦٦٦٦٦)
2. +97172466666 (+٩٧١٧٢٤٦٦٦٦٦)

You may convert them to Arabic numbers to test?

**Update 2:**

After using the RegEx (`"^(?:\\+٩٧١|٠(٠٩٧١)?)(?:[٢٣٤٦٧٩]|٥[٠١٢٥٦])[٠-٩]{7}$"`) which is provided by rmaddy it's stopped crashing but still it's not detecting whether it's a valid number or not.

Comment: The `{7}` needs to stay `{7}` in the Arabic expression and it needs to stay after the `[0-9]` equivalent.

Comment: You've also reversed way too much of the regular expression. You need to keep the regular expression syntax in the correct order. Just reverse the order that each part of the number can be in.

Comment: @rmaddy, I didn't know but it was changed its order automatically. I will try to correct it and will check it again. Do you know any tool online to do it easily?

Comment: I came up with `let phoneRegExAr = "^(?:\\+٩٧١|٠(٠٩٧١)?)(?:[٢٣٤٦٧٩]|٥[٠١٢٥٦])[٠-٩]{7}$"` but since you didn't provide any test cases in your question I can't test it. (That's not how it looks in Xcode).

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, let me check this. If this will work I will ask you to write an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @rmaddy, please check the screenshot in question, I don't know but StackOverflow changed the way I write this in Xcode. So mine RegEx is same as yours. I haven't changed anything. Let me give you some test numbers which you can check? I'll update numbers in my question.

Comment: My RE is not the same. See my first comment and the RE I posted.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. I missed it. I will check with your RegEx now. Thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have updated the question (can you please check the update-2)?

Comment: The RE I have in Xcode works just fine with the two examples you posted. But when I copy and paste the RE from Xcode into these comments, it gets messed up. Must be some sort of RTL/LTR issue.

Comment: your Regex worked  check this test https://regex101.com/r/oSa3bN/1

Comment: @Ahmed, thanks! somehow this isn't working for me right now.

Comment: @rmaddy, I request you to add your comments as answer so I can accept it. I believe, since it's working for you guys it should work for me too. I'll check them later.

Comment: I tried several times but I couldn't. My attempt to copy and paste or to type the RE into the answer below resulted in a garbled mess, hence my previous comment.

Comment: Is the issue fixed? Note it might be a better idea to match these digits using Unicode code units, like `\uXXXX`.

Comment: Yes, the issue was fixed. I needed to re-order the arabic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There is described the [Arabic script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) (source: Wikipedia) and the range is from `U+0600` to `U+06FF` so the regex such as:

```
([\u0600-\u06FF]+)
```

Should work. And it does ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AcrRKC/2)). For the digits only, use the range between `U+0660` and `U+0669`.